# Best French equivalent to "two peas in a pod"? — Équivalent français de l'expression « like two peas in a pod »

Tags: traduction, anglais, proverbes, expressions-idiomatiques

In English, there's the expression "like two peas in a pod", which refers to two things—often people—that are very similar to each other.  For example, you might say:

> We liked the same places, the same foods, and the same games.  We were like two peas in a pod.

Does French have an equivalent expression to express this kind of similarity?

---

En anglais l'expression « like two peas in a pod » est utilisée pour désigner deux choses, ou plus souvent deux personnes, très semblables l'une à l'autre. Par exemple :

> On aime les mêmes endroits, la même nourriture, les mêmes jeux. On est *like two peas in a pod*.

Y a-t'il une expression équivalente en français permettant de décrire ce genre de ressemblance ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To insist on the similarity between people and things, the best might be **“se ressembler [comme deux gouttes d'eau](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_deux_gouttes_d%E2%80%99eau)”**. I believe that's the canonical translation for *“two peas in a pod”*. It deals with similarity between people or things, whether physical (which would be the assumed meaning, if there is no other context) or otherwise.

Shlublu offers translations for expressions for people being really close, but I think the meaning of “peas in a pod” is more about similarity than sticking together (or knowing each other). I would add one expression that is somewhat more generic, and can encompass both the idea of being alike, and being well together: **“à deux, elles font la paire”**.

Comment: Of course! How can I have forgotten that one!

Comment: For me, _se ressembler comme deux gouttes d'eau_ only deals with physical ressemblance. The original _two peas in a pod_ caries more than that, as explained by the OP.

Comment: @Joubarc *se ressembler comme deux gouttes d'eau* refers to the physical ressemblance if no context is specified: *Alain et Fred se ressemblent comme deux gouttes d'eau* will be understood that way. But it can work for moral or pychological ressemblance as well if the context is specified: *Moralement, Alain et Pierre...* or the phrase included in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so - and it's not like I can think of anything better myself. Still, I do prefer _comme les deux doigts de la main_ in this case.

Comment: Les deux gouttes d'eau sont effectivement un bon équivalent des pois dans une gousse. Je signale aussi l'expression « [bonnet blanc et blanc bonnet](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonnet_blanc,_blanc_bonnet) », équivalente à [Tweedledum and Tweedledee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedledum_and_Tweedledee) (en Belgique on dit « [chou vert et vert chou](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schtroumpf_vert_et_Vert_Schtroumpf) »), pour deux choses semblables sous des apparences non identiques.

Answer (score 9):

None of them is a completely accurate translation, but given the context of the phrase you used as an example:

- In France we use the expression *comme cul et chemise* (which is, once litterally translated, something like *as ass and shirt*). Even though it contains the word *cul* it is not offending, just familiar. You can sometimes hear it in "G rated" TV shows.

> We liked the same places, the same foods, and the same games. We were like two peas in a pod.

Would give:

> On aimait les mêmes lieux, la même cuisine, et les mêmes jeux. On était comme cul et chemise.

This said, I dont like it so much.

- You can also use *inséparables*. It is appropriate in all situations but it is a quite less accurate translation:

> On aimait les mêmes lieux, la même cuisine, et les mêmes jeux. On était inséparables.

- And you can also use *être comme les deux doigts de la main* (which means something like *to be like two fingers of a hand*):

> On aimait les mêmes lieux, la même cuisine, et les mêmes jeux. On était comme les deux doigts de la main.

It is not fully accurate either: *être comme les deux doigts de la main* implies a strong moral commitment and suggests that each *finger* can absolutely stand by the other one.

Comment: “Comme cul et chemise” et “comme les deux doigts de la main” would be closer to “go together like peanut butter and jelly”, I think.

Comment: Alors, I should mention the related “comme larrons en foire”, which would be closer to “as thick as thieves”…

Comment: Yes, that's completely right @F'x. Close but not 100% accurate. And very context-dependant.

Comment: @F'x: Agreed that "cul et chemise" could also be translated "peanut butter and jelly" (though that expression is very US-centric and won't really make much sense in most other English-speaking countries), but I still think it's one of the closest equivalent to "peas in a pod" (despite its very familiar overtone). "Deux gouttes d'eau" is too focussed on physical similarity, imho.

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que la réponse de F'x est la plus courante et celle qui ira le mieux dans la grande majorité des cas (et était d'ailleurs déjà très à la mode fin XVIII<sup>e</sup>).

On pourra cependant noter aussi quelques autres expressions, parfois tombées en désuétude, mais qui ont l'avantage de chatouiller les oreilles ;)

- *Comme de cire* (XVI<sup>e</sup> - *"On dit de deux hommes de même humeur, de même inclination, qu'ils sont égaux comme de cire"* - Dictionnaire des proverbes - Quitard, 1842). Conviendrait parfaitement à l'exemple donné par l'OP mais a disparu depuis longtemps de la langue si je ne m'abuse.
- *Avoir été coulé dans le même moule* (milieu XVII<sup>e</sup> mais qui ne me choque pas et qu'on entend encore parfois)
- *Ils sont de [la] même étoffe* (milieu XVII<sup>e</sup> - Utilisable)
- *Ils sont du même calibre* (milieu XVII<sup>e</sup> - Utilisable)
- *Ils sont du même acabit* (XVIII<sup>e</sup> sens péjoratif)
- *Taupin vaut marotte* ou *Taupin vaut taupine* (milieu XIX<sup>e</sup> - *de deux personnes qui ont les mêmes vices ou la même laideur physique* - Dictionnaire de la langue verte - Delvau, 1867). Inconnu au bataillon pour ma part !
- *Ils sont du même tonneau* (fin XIX<sup>e</sup> - Utilisable bien que vieilli je pense)

Comment: À part *comme de cire* (disparu de la langue, même s'il se comprend facilement dans le contexte), je trouve ces expressions moins fortes en termes de similitude que *peas in a pod* ou *deux gouttes d'eau*.

Answer (score 1):

Another one biased towards physical resemblance:

> On aurait dit des jumeaux.